# How does one print a Unicode character code in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I would like to print a unicode's character code, and not the actual glyph it represents in Python.

For example, if `u` is a list of unicode characters:

```
>>> u[0]
u'\u0103'
>>> print u[0]
ă
```

I would like to output the character code as a raw string: `u'\u0103'`.

I have tried to just print it to a file, but this doesn't work without encoding it in `UTF-8`.

```
>>> w = open('~/foo.txt', 'w')
>>> print>>w, u[0].decode('utf-8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    print>>w, u[0].decode('utf-8')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0103' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print>>w, u[0].encode('utf-8')
>>> w.close()
```

Encoding it results in the glyph `ă` being written to the file.

How can I write the character code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For printing raw unicode data one only need specify the correct encoding:

```
>>> s = u'\u0103'
>>> print s.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
\u0103
```