# In Python 3 how to print unicode codepoint as u'\U...'

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-16

For whatever reason, I thought it would be neat to create a table of emoji I'm interested in.  First column would be the codepoint, second the emoji, third the name.  SOmething along the lines of this web page, but tailored to my use.

[Full emoji data](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f605)

Assuming I figure out how to iterate on the codepoints (there are other questions for that or I construct a list of interest) then I will just cycle through the code points such as

```
u_str = u'\U0001F001'
u_str = u'\U0001F002'
```

(generated programmatically of course)

and print (in a loop):

```
print(u'\U0001F001', u_str, ' ', unicodedata.name(u_str))
print(u'\U0001F002', u_str, ' ', unicodedata.name(u_str))
```

If there was an ability to use unicodedata and some attribute such as unicodedata.hex_representation then I would just use that, but if there is that attribute in unicodedata, I don't understand the spec to see it.

So in searching for an answer I found this question:

[how-does-one-print-a-unicode-character-code-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435855/how-does-one-print-a-unicode-character-code-in-python)

I attempt:

```
>>> print(u_str.encode('raw_unicode_escape'))
b'\\U0001f600'
```

what I'm looking for is what I put in:

```
u_str = u'\U0001F600'
```

Is this possible or is there some other way to achieve the construction of the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Python 3.6+:

```
>>> for i in range(0x1f001,0x1f005):
>>>     print(f'U+{i:04X} \\U{i:08X} {chr(i)}')
U+1F001 \U0001F001 
U+1F002 \U0001F002 
U+1F003 \U0001F003 
U+1F004 \U0001F004
```

Comment: perfect!  I upvoted too, but it won't record until my reputation goes above 15.

Comment: I tried your example, but got an error: ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)

Comment: @Y.Wang Question is for Python 3. `unichr` is used in Python 2, but has other limitations. On Windows, use at least Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 1):

1. The original representation is gone forever. The case and formatting are specified by Python itself.
2. You need to decode your bytes back to text. Try the `ascii` codec, since that's all `raw_unicode_escape` will generate.

Comment: print(u_str.encode('ascii')) // UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f002' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)  It is:    GRINNING FACE.

Comment: Nowhere does my answer state that you need to encode the original text.

Comment: You encoded the text. That gives you bytes. Now you need to decode the bytes back into text.